# Android assign to textview

Tags: android

I want to assign data from database to textview or variable. But i get an error when assigning a value to textview or variable. When i Log to display the data it is OK.

Error:
    Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Here is the code:

```
try {
            String sql = "SELECT Cname FROM demo";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                  TextView txtValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            txtValue.setText(rs.getString("Cname"));

            }
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error implies you need to set the text on the main thread.

You can post a message via the `TextView`, so it runs on the UI thread:

```
final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
...
final TextView txtValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
txtValue.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        txtValue.setText(rs.getString("Cname"));
    }
});
```